# Flutter get error "Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain"

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to run my project , I am getting error

Launching lib/main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to know the problem with so little information. One general approach with worked to me was performing:

```
flutter clean
```

Try to run.
If it does not run **delete the jar file** under android/gradle/properties to recompile it and try again.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I download repo from cloud and rename.
If work with repo with original name - so good.

Answer (score 0):

if Your project in folder with name Arabic rename to English its fix it with me

Comment: the question didn't talk about any location problem.